# Express and Websocket to run on the same port on the same file

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, port, vps

I'm running two apps that sends real-time messages to each other using websocket and also generate a random link using express.js, now i hosted the server with both react apps to my vps host and want to make the websocket connection secure (wss://) but i realize i'll have to get the express server on the same port too, so the ssl/tsl works for both - so how do i do that?

Here is my full code, all on the same file:

```
const webSocketServerPort = 8000;

const webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(); server.listen(webSocketServerPort); console.log('Listening on port 8000');

const wsServer = new webSocketServer({ httpServer: server })

//GEERTOOOO

const express = require('express'); const cors = require('cors'); const fs = require('fs'); const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => { // Generate a random 6-character string const linkId = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 6);

// Save the link in the lex.json file fs.readFile('lex.json', (err, data) => { if (err) { console.error(err); res.status(500).send('Error generating link'); return; }

const links = JSON.parse(data);
links[linkId] = {
  destination: 'http://localhost:4000/',
  expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 5  // expires in 5 minutes
};
fs.writeFile('lex.json', JSON.stringify(links), (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Error generating link');
    return;
  }

  // Send the link back to the client
  res.send(`http://localhost:3000/${linkId}`);
});

}); });

app.get('/:linkId', (req, res) => {
 fs.readFile('lex.json', (err, data) => {
if (err) { console.error(err); res.status(500).send('Error retrieving link'); 
return;
}

const links = JSON.parse(data);
const link = links[req.params.linkId];
if (!link) {
  res.status(404).send('Link not found');
  return;
}

// Check if the link has expired
if (link.expires < Date.now()) {
  res.status(410).send('Link has expired');
  return;
}

// Redirect to the destination
res.redirect(link.destination);
}); });

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('Server listening on port 3000'); });

//GEERTOOOO

const clients = {};

const getUniqueID = () => { const s4 = () => Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);

return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4(); }

wsServer.on('request', (request) => { var userID = getUniqueID();

const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin); clients[userID] = connection;

connection.on('message', (message) => {
if (message.type === 'utf8') {

  for(var key in clients) {
    if (clients[key] !== clients[userID]) {
      clients[key].sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
      console.log(`Sent Message to: ${clients[key]}`);
    }
  }
}
}) })
```

Note: the express server is on port 3000 and the websocket server runs on port 8000.

I,ve tried just changing the port to same thing but i get an error when trying to use the websocket server for messages.

THE PURPOSE OF ALL THIS IS JUST TO MAKE THE WEBSOCKET CONNECTION AND EXPRESS CONNECCTION SECURE SO MY APPS (with letsencrypt ssl) can connect to the servers

Comment: I can't really tell what problem you're asking us for help with.  It is possible to run a webSocket on the same port as your express server.  But, you have to share one server instance on one port, not try to create two separate server instances both on the same port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to create two separate server instances, both listening on the same port.  But, specifically for a webSocket, you can share one server instance between Express and the webSocket server code.  This is possible because a webSocket connection always starts with an http request (thus it can be listened for using your Express http server.   And, because these http requests that initiate a webSocket all contain identifying headers they can be separated out from the regular http requests for Express by looking at the headers.  The webSocket server code already knows how to do that for you.

To do that, first capture the Express server instance:

```
const server = app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('Server listening on port 3000'); });
```

Then, use that `server` instance when you create your webSocket server.

```
const wsServer = new webSocketServer({ httpServer: server });
```

---

Then, remove this code because you don't want to create yet another http server instance for the webSocket server:

```
const server = http.createServer(); 
server.listen(webSocketServerPort); 
console.log('Listening on port 8000');
```

Comment: wow! @jfriend00, that's one hell of a simple and accurate answer. My code now works perfectly on the same port, thanks for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: I literally made my account and built up my reputation just so that I can say thank you. Such a simple solution, but one that had escaped me. Very much appreciated!